# Setting IPV4 settings to default, A.I. "Obtain an IP address automatically", C#

Tags: c#, ip, ipv4

i am developing a utility to change ip and subnet mask, but id love to be able to change it back to default, or at least set it to "Obtain an IP address automatically.

```
public void setIPAndSub(string ip_address, string subnet_mask)
{
    ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
    ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();

    foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
    {
        if ((bool)objMO["IPEnabled"])
        {
            try
            {
                ManagementBaseObject setIP;
                ManagementBaseObject newIP = objMO.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic");

                newIP["IPAddress"] = new string[] { ip_address };
                newIP["SubnetMask"] = new string[] { subnet_mask };

                setIP = objMO.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", newIP, null);
                MessageBox.Show("Setup complete");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is from an example and works. What i am missing is a method for resetting the settings... 
Or "Obtain an IP address automatically".
I literally have no idea where to start, i have been doing some research online, but i just dont have the knowledge to get anything i find, to work.

Answer (score 0):

To enable DHCP ("Obtain an IP address automatically" means use DHCP/autoip):

```
objMO.InvokeMethod("EnableDHCP", null, null);
```

See documentation for the [Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217(v=vs.85).aspx) for more information.